# Error in MySQL database installer syntax for chat system

Tags: mysql, syntax

I have spent the past week mulling over this single MySQL document with no luck as to figuring out what/where the error is that's stopping it from properly installing it's self so I can have the chat system it's for up and running. I would go to the developer but he's essentially been unresponsive for over a year now so I have given up on help from him. The error I am getting upon trying to install it is the following :

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server >version for the right syntax to use near '(14) NOT NULL, userid int(11) default NULL, >banneduserid int(11) default NULL, r' at line 1

The MySQL file reads as follows :

```
#--------------------------------------------------------------------------
# Table structure for table `bans`
#--------------------------------------------------------------------------

CREATE TABLE `bans` (
       `created` timestamp(14) NOT NULL,
       `userid` int(11) default NULL,
       `banneduserid` int(11) default NULL,
       `roomid` int(11) default NULL,
       `ip` varchar(16) default NULL,
       KEY `userid` (`userid`),
       KEY `created` (`created`)
     ) ENGINE=MyISAM;

#--------------------------------------------------------------------------
# Table structure for table `connections`
#--------------------------------------------------------------------------

CREATE TABLE `connections` (
       `id` varchar(32) NOT NULL default '',
       `updated` timestamp(14) NOT NULL,
       `created` timestamp(14) NOT NULL,
       `userid` int(11) default NULL,
       `roomid` int(11) default NULL,
       `state` tinyint(4) NOT NULL default '1',
       `color` int(11) default NULL,
       `start` int(11) default NULL,
       `lang` char(2) default NULL,
       `ip` varchar(16) default NULL,
       `tzoffset` int(11) default '0',
       `chatid` int(11) NOT NULL default '1',
       PRIMARY KEY  (`id`),
       KEY `userid` (`userid`),
       KEY `roomid` (`roomid`),
       KEY `updated` (`updated`)
     ) ENGINE=MyISAM;

#--------------------------------------------------------------------------
# Table structure for table `ignors`
#--------------------------------------------------------------------------

CREATE TABLE `ignors` (
       `created` timestamp(14) NOT NULL,
       `userid` int(11) default NULL,
       `ignoreduserid` int(11) default NULL,
       KEY `userid` (`userid`),
       KEY `ignoreduserid` (`ignoreduserid`),
       KEY `created` (`created`)
     ) ENGINE=MyISAM;

#--------------------------------------------------------------------------
# Table structure for table `messages`
#--------------------------------------------------------------------------

CREATE TABLE `messages` (
       `id` int(11) NOT NULL auto_increment,
       `created` timestamp(14) NOT NULL,
       `toconnid` varchar(32) default NULL,
       `touserid` int(11) default NULL,
       `toroomid` int(11) default NULL,
       `command` varchar(255) NOT NULL default '',
       `userid` int(11) default NULL,
       `roomid` int(11) default NULL,
       `txt` text,
       PRIMARY KEY  (`id`),
       KEY `touserid` (`touserid`),
       KEY `toroomid` (`toroomid`),
       KEY `toconnid` (`toconnid`),
       KEY `created` (`created`)
     ) ENGINE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=14 ;

#--------------------------------------------------------------------------
# Table structure for table `rooms`
#--------------------------------------------------------------------------

CREATE TABLE `rooms` (
       `id` int(11) NOT NULL auto_increment,
       `updated` timestamp(14) NOT NULL,
       `created` timestamp(14) NOT NULL,
       `name` varchar(64) NOT NULL default '',
       `password` varchar(32) NOT NULL default '', 
       `ispublic` char(1) default NULL,
       `ispermanent` int(11) default NULL,

       PRIMARY KEY  (`id`),
       KEY `name` (`name`),
       KEY `ispublic` (`ispublic`),
       KEY `ispermanent` (`ispermanent`),
       KEY `updated` (`updated`)
     ) ENGINE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=5 ;

#--------------------------------------------------------------------------
# Table structure for table `users`
#--------------------------------------------------------------------------

CREATE TABLE `users` (
       `id` int(11) NOT NULL auto_increment,
       `login` varchar(32) NOT NULL default '',
       `password` varchar(32) NOT NULL default '',
       `roles` int(11) NOT NULL default '0',
       `profile` text,
       PRIMARY KEY  (`id`),
       KEY `login` (`login`)
     ) ENGINE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=2 ;
```

My guess is that there is an older call/request that is out dated and no longer used for the version of MySQL I have installed on my host ( Version : 5.5.19 ). I really appreciate any help I can get with this so I can finally stop running off of a flat file ( the other install option this thing has ) and integrate it into my CMS. Thank you for your time!

-Reiz

Answer (score 1):

Remove the `(14)` from all your timestamp types like that

```
... column_name timestamp NOT NULL ...
```

Answer (score 1):

In MySQL versions after 4.1 the `timestamp` datatype has no properties added in brackets.

[MySQL Docu 4.1](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/4.1/en/timestamp-pre-4-1.html)

[MySQL Docu 5.1](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/datetime.html)

So in your case just drop the `(14)` after all appearances of `timestamp` in the sql. So, e.g., change this

```
 `created` timestamp(14) NOT NULL,
```

to this

```
 `created` timestamp NOT NULL,
```